# Operation canceled error in async_write

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

I am trying to send a large amount of data around 50KByte or above over a TCP socket using the following command in C++:

```
boost::asio::async_write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(sbuff, slen),
             boost::bind((&send_handler), placeholders::error));
```

Where `sbuff` is a pointer to the data to be transmitted, and `slen` is the length of the data.

Sometimes the operation successes and sometimes I get an error with `Operation cancelled`

Here is the code part for the receiver, waiting for a specific amount of the data to be received.

```
    boost::asio::async_read(_sock,
        boost::asio::buffer(rbuf, rlen),
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read_payload,
        this,
        placeholders::bytes_transferred,
        placeholders::error));

void session::handle_read_payload(buffer<uint8> &buff, size_t rbytes, const boost::system::error_code &e)
```

Where `rlen` is the number of the bytes to wait to receive. And `rbuf` is a pointer to where I store the received bytes.

I checked the flow of the TCP packets between the two machines using Wireshark and I found that suddenly the receiver sends back a packet with FIN flag set to the sender, which terminates the connection.

So can anyone tell me what might be the root of the problem? IS there any problem with my code?

Does it matter if I call `_acceptor.listen();` before `async_accept`. Because when I tested without `_acceptor.listen();` , it works perfectly. So what would be the difference?

Comment: Are you seeing an error on the receiving end, too?  If so is it possible to tell which end detects the error first?

Comment: No error at the receiver side. Only the sender side

Comment: I assume rlen <= slen, and handle_read_payload does something useful with the data then issues another async_read. Are my assumptions valid?

Comment: rlen is smaller than slen, because at the beginning I read the header of the message and then I read its payload. And in the handle_read_payload I don't do any async_read any more what I do is I close the socket and then when a sender wants to send me a message he needs to re-establish a new tcp connection again.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to reflect the information in your last comment.   And my next question: When the sender sees the error, has the receiver closed the socket?  Also (another assumption) I'm guessing that the header length field is a 2 byte unsigned integer.  Is it possible that slen is occasionally > 2^16?

Comment: The header length is 4 bytes. From the wireshark after receiving two segments the receiver closes the socket suddenly. The maximum value of the slen is 2^16 bytes.

Comment: don't want to ask the obvious, but... are you using a timer as well? does the object containing `sock_` live long enough?

Comment: @sehe I am not using any timer at all. The object which contains the _sock lives till the end of the connection. The _sock.close() won't be called until all the message bytes have been received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments to the question, it sounds very much like there is a disagreement between the sender and the receiver about the size of the message being sent.

The receiver receives what it thinks is a complete message then closes the socket while the sender still thinks there is more data that the receiver has not accepted.

To diagnose the problem, I suggest that you display slen on the sender side, and display rlen on the receiver side before issuing the respective read/write requests (by display I mean write to a log or to std::cerr or whatever other approach works for your application.)  If the two numbers are not equal you know where to look for the underlying cause of the problem.  If they are equal -- then more investigation will be needed.

Comment: You are correct about your anaylsis. But now I found something strage, in the call `boost::asio::async_write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(sbuff, slen), boost::bind((&send_handler), placeholders::error));` The value of `slen` is 100412 bytes. But on the wire, I can only find 65535 bytes. Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: That is being addressed in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795586/