# TCP socket sending less number of bytes

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, boost-asio

I am trying to send a large number of bytes using boost.asio library as following:

```
void tcp_send(boost::asio::io_service &io, const char *dst_ip, uint16 dst_port)
{
    uint8 *sbuff;
    size_t slen;
    ip::tcp::socket sock(io);

    sock.connect(ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string(dst_ip), dst_port));

    sbuff = new uint8[100412];
    sbuff[0] = 67;
    sbuff[1] = 193;
    sbuff[2] = 136;
    sbuff[3] = 60;

    boost::asio::async_write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(sbuff, 100412),
             boost::bind((&send_handler), placeholders::error));
}
```

When I check the number of transmitted bytes using wireshark, the sender sends always and only 65536 bytes of data excluding TCP header bytes. So what might be the problem?
Is there any parameter I need to modify.

I am running the application on linux ubuntu. It seems that the maximum number of transmitted bytes is 2^16.

[image: Wireshark TCP Stream Flow]

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a **stream**. How many bytes appear in the IP datagrams or Ethernet frames should be of no concern to you.

Successfully calling `send` doesn't necessarily even mean that the data was sent yet; just that the TCP stack accepted the data and promises to send it (unless you specify PSH).

Comment: So what should I do in my case to let all the 100412 bytes goes out? 
Actually I did not have the problem when I was using the Berkeley sockets directly, but now I have this problem with the boost wrappers.

Comment: Not sure how you've got the rest of your stuff implemented but you might try tracking it in `send_handler`.

Comment: Please can you check my new edit I provided the wireshark output.

The `send_handler` is only for error handling

Comment: `send_handler` is called when the send is complete, whether it is successful or not. Let it tell you if the full buffer was sent, or if the send failed. Chances are, it is failing after sending 65536 bytes. TCP cannot send 100412 bytes in a single packet, so `async_write()` should be sending multiple packets until either the `buffer` is exhausted or an error occurs.

Comment: I tried now to replace `boost::asio::async_write()` with `boost::asio::write`, and the operation succeeded. I was able to see all the bytes in the wireshark. Can anyone explain to me what is happening?
@Remy You are correct, but I am not getting any error in the send_handler at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the source of the problem. First of all, I was trying to send the message by using tcp_Send function and after it returns from the call, I exist the program. Because of this the TCP stack does not have enough time to send all the packets in its buffer. So I should give it some time.

Now in the second trial, I kept the application running after sending the message, but now I got an error in the `send_handler`, which states `bad file descriptor`. And this due to that the socket being declared is destroyed after exiting the `tcp_send` function. So to solve this issue I should define the socket as a pointer. Or the best thing is to use write instead of async_Write

Comment: That won't cause data loss. When you destroy the `ip::tcp::socket`, the underlying socket is closed but all pending data remains in the socket send buffer for eventual transmission, followed by an orderly close (TCP `FIN`). However it may not have all been sent at the moment your program exits.

Comment: I haven't tested it recently, but it used to be that in Windows (XP and earlier) exiting a process would discard any unsent data from the network stack, whereas on *nix systems the data would still be sent eventually. A real PITA for Windows programmers since there was no good way to ask if the data had really been sent.